# psql not worked expected in terminal: psql: error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, terminal

There are three things involved in this question.

1. I use postgres.app on MacOS Big Sur Version 13.
2. The terminal with the PATH added to the profile ( able to use psql in terminal)
3. Postico (An MacOS client for postgreSQL)

I initialized the server in the PostgresSQL App. There are three database

1. template1
2. postgres
3. myusername

There are no password authentication when I access any of the three database through PostgresSQL.app and Postico.

But when I come to terminal and it is asking for password authentication in all three database.

I did some digging before I decide to post here, I can only figure out the password for database postgres is postgres. I don't know the password for the other two.

I also checked the **pg_hba.conf** and made sure all the authentication method is set to trust.

below is my **pg_hba.conf**:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                    trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

If I run `ps ax | grep postgres`

It return the following:

```
22541   ??  Ss     0:00.01 postgres: logger
22543   ??  Ss     0:00.03 postgres: checkpointer
22544   ??  Ss     0:00.39 postgres: background writer
22545   ??  Ss     0:00.36 postgres: walwriter
22546   ??  Ss     0:00.27 postgres: autovacuum launcher
22547   ??  Ss     0:00.96 postgres: stats collector
22548   ??  Ss     0:00.02 postgres: logical replication launcher
25547   ??  Ss     0:00.14 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/bin/postgres -D /Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-13 -p 8000
25549   ??  Ss     0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer
25550   ??  Ss     0:00.12 postgres: background writer
25551   ??  Ss     0:00.06 postgres: walwriter
25552   ??  Ss     0:00.12 postgres: autovacuum launcher
25553   ??  Ss     0:00.41 postgres: stats collector
25554   ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: logical replication launcher
26146 s002  R+     0:00.00 grep postgres
```

running `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN`

```
remoted      75            root    4u  IPv6 0x689109d1d8a134db      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49153 (LISTEN)
remoted      75            root    5u  IPv6 0x689109d1d8a13b3b      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49154 (LISTEN)
remoted      75            root    6u  IPv6 0x689109d1d8a1419b      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49155 (LISTEN)
remoted      75            root    7u  IPv6 0x689109d1d8a1281b      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49156 (LISTEN)
remoted      75            root    8u  IPv6 0x689109d1d94cbe7b      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49157 (LISTEN)
remoted      75            root    9u  IPv6 0x689109d1d94cc4db      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49158 (LISTEN)
rapportd  18282  zhengyangzhang    6u  IPv4 0x689109d1fd26f02b      0t0    TCP *:50441 (LISTEN)
rapportd  18282  zhengyangzhang    7u  IPv6 0x689109d1face319b      0t0    TCP *:50441 (LISTEN)
Mountain  18359  zhengyangzhang  297u  IPv6 0x689109d1f4ea319b      0t0    TCP localhost:60444 (LISTEN)
Dropbox   19634  zhengyangzhang   81u  IPv4 0x689109d1f2dd702b      0t0    TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox   19634  zhengyangzhang   82u  IPv6 0x689109d1face481b      0t0    TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox   19634  zhengyangzhang  122u  IPv4 0x689109d1fd437d1b      0t0    TCP localhost:17600 (LISTEN)
Dropbox   19634  zhengyangzhang  127u  IPv4 0x689109d1fd43916b      0t0    TCP localhost:17603 (LISTEN)
postgres  22540        postgres    7u  IPv6 0x689109d1f2eed4db      0t0    TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres  22540        postgres    8u  IPv4 0x689109d1fd26dbdb      0t0    TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
TextMate  23423  zhengyangzhang   22u  IPv6 0x689109d1face619b      0t0    TCP localhost:52698 (LISTEN)
Spotify   25362  zhengyangzhang   31u  IPv4 0x689109d1fd93202b      0t0    TCP *:51214 (LISTEN)
Spotify   25362  zhengyangzhang   51u  IPv4 0x689109d1fd49e8cb      0t0    TCP *:57621 (LISTEN)
idea      25639  zhengyangzhang   24u  IPv6 0x689109d1fc0b481b      0t0    TCP localhost:6942 (LISTEN)
idea      25639  zhengyangzhang   29u  IPv6 0x689109d1fc0b4e7b      0t0    TCP localhost:63342 (LISTEN)
idea      25639  zhengyangzhang   70u  IPv6 0x689109d1fc0b6e7b      0t0    TCP localhost:51705 (LISTEN)
java      25668  zhengyangzhang   62u  IPv6 0x689109d1f2fa44db      0t0    TCP localhost:49096 (LISTEN)
java      25668  zhengyangzhang   63u  IPv6 0x689109d1f2fa381b      0t0    TCP localhost:51699 (LISTEN)
```

I would love to put something reproducible here, but for this issue there is nothing I can put except the error message which is already included in the title.

so I don't really know what I should do here, somebody please help me.

Comment: What arguments do you use with psql?  Are you specifying a host?

Comment: Isn't "PostgresSQL.app" just a package that installs other things, like `pg_ctl` and `psql`?  What does it mean to log in "through PostgresSQL.app"

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing `pg_hba.conf`?  Add the contents of `pg_hba.conf` to your question. Roles and passwords are global to the cluster(all the databases) so you should be able to log into the other databases as user `postgres` with that users password.  In any case log into the `postgres` database and do `select * from pg_shadow ;` that will show you the roles(users) and whether they have passwords. The passwords will be hashes so you can't their plain text form.

Comment: if I only type in ```psql``` in terminal, the default is my username database and is asking for a password.  @Jeremy

Comment: what I meant is when you open the PostgresSQL.app, you can click start the server right? When you start the server, it will have three default database as I mentioned in the question right? If I click on any of the three database there, it will either take me to its database in terminal or postico based on my setting, it's not asking for any password. @jjanes

Comment: I did, I tried multiple times, all asking for password. I also just tried the ```select * from pg_shadow; ``` in the postgres database, it returns one role - postgres and  I am not sure what does that mean. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: What is the exact `psql` connection string you are using? Is there another instance of Postgres running? In other words in the command terminal what does `ps ax | grep postgres` return? The `pg_shadow` result means you have only one role defined for the cluster(the three databases). Where are you running `select * from pg_shadow;?

Comment: I run ``` psql -U postgres ```, then asking for password, I type in postgres, it give me access to the postgres database. I run  ```select * from pg_shadow; ```, it only return one role named postgres. I will put the  ```ps ax | grep postgres```  in the question.

Comment: Well something is amiss as the port the server is shown to be running on is `8000`, yet `psql -U postgres` will default to `5432`.  Try `psql -U postgres -d postgres -p 8000` and report the result back as update to your question. It looks like you have two instances of Postgres running.

Comment: I created this server, I use 8000 port number, because 5432 is giving me error.  ```Usually this means that there is already a PostgreSQL server running on your Mac. If you want to run multiple servers simultaneously, use different ports. ``` But the problem is there is only one server.. so I don't know how is port 5432 already in use.

Comment: Because there is another Postgres server running. At some point you installed another instance of Postgres, maybe even another instance of postgresql.app.  The `ps ax |grep postgres` output looks like it cut off the top of which would show you what that Postgres instance is. Rerun the command and see if you can see the instance.

Comment: On Linux I can do `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN` to see what is listening on what port. You might try that in the command terminal to see if works.

Comment: And yes, I did install postgres.app before, and then I wiped out my computer because of some issue, I thought everything on my mac would be wiped out except those file I backed on icloud.. I didn't know the postgres I installed before still here.. I have updated the question!

Comment: I do not see the `8000` port listed. Did you shut that instance down? In any case, unless you want to run > 1 instance, you need to decide which one to keep and make the appropriate changes to the conf files for that instance. Also, in future remember error messages are there for a reason and while they may not always  be 100% correct, ignoring them is generally not a good idea:)

Comment: I deleted that server, now I just want to delete the 5432 server too and restart, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236269/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-zzy09ys).

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was, before I install the postgre.app, I accidentally download the EDB Wizard Installer for PostgreSQL. Then I realized this is not what I want, I did not complete clean out the Wizard Installer for PostgreSQL.

That's why it's causing the issue I have above.

The PostgreSQL folder would be in /Library on Mac, can be accessed through `cd /Library`. Once you access it, you can click on the uninstaller and delete the data, the issue would be fixed.